# how to delete child record from firebase in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to delete this record in `firebase`, where i don't have the name of the key. so, I don't know how to do it. can anybody help me with this?

The code for getting array is as follows

```
var databaseRefer : DatabaseReference!
  let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
 databaseRefer = Database.database().reference(withPath: userID!)
 databaseRefer.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
         if !snapshot.exists() { return }
          if snapshot.value is NSNull {
           print("not found")
            } else {
                for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot

                   print(dict)

                   dict.forEach { item in

                       print(item.value)
               }
             }
       }
   })
```

[image]

Comment: @NiravD I want to delete it using code.

Comment: Are you having reference of that child ?

Comment: @NiravD No. I dont have the reference. what I have is the array of the time and I want to delete one of the child dynamically.

Comment: Please show us the code that you are using to get all this array of time also you want to remove child that is not having month in MMM format right ?

Comment: @NiravD please check my updated question

Comment: What is dict in your code, there is no declaration of it don't you getting any error ?

Comment: To delete items from the database, you must know *something* that identifies those items. What **do** you know off the child you want to remove? E.g. do you know the date (and is that unique)? Do you know the `cate_id` (and is that unique)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

"The simplest way to delete data is to call removeValue on a reference to the location of that data."